# Select2.js - How do I prevent displaying the tags?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, jquery-select2

I've got select2.js setup something like this:

```
        $searchBar.select2({
            maximumSelectionSize: 1
            , minimumInputLength: 1
            , multiple: true
            , placeholder: 'Search'
        });
```

I'm sure this in the docs and right in front of my face, but is there any way to disable the tags from showing up?

I've got two workarounds for now but both have some annoying side-effects:

1) Re-render the input box each time I do a selection

2) use css to hide the tags with display: none;

Comment: To clarify, you want the dropdown with the options (tags) to be hidden, is that it? In other words, you don't want to show the "suggestions"?

Comment: I do want the dropdown with the options.  I just don't want the little boxes that show up after a search term has been selected.  The ones that get `maximumSelectionSize ` applies to.  Something like setting maximumSelectionSize to 0 would be great but that basically just makes maximumSelectionSize unlimited.

Comment: Oh, I see what you want. I don't think there's an option to hide the tags you've selected. I guess the best way you can do that is with css, like you said. `.select2-search-choice { display: none; }`

Comment: Thanks, yeah, the downside of that is that code thinks its displaying a tag, but the user doesn't see it.  This results in strange behavior/messaging when the user thinks they've cleared the search box but the library thinks there's still this tag in there.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this by hooking into the 'select2-selecting' event and altering the behavior like this:

```
$('select2-select-element')
    .select2()
    .on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('input.select2-input').val(e.object.text);
      $('.select2-drop').hide();
    });
```

It works pretty close to how you describe.